# Leetcode Sum of Subarray Minimums passing 86/87 tests. Probably an Issue with my modulo calculation

Tags: java, modulo

I am solving the Sum of Subarray Minimums problem in leetcode.

Problem description -
Given an array of integers arr, find the sum of min(b), where b ranges over every (contiguous) subarray of arr. Since the answer may be large, return the answer modulo (10^9) + 7.

Problem Example -

Input: arr = [3,1,2,4]

Output: 17

Explanation:

Subarrays are [3], [1], [2], [4], [3,1], [1,2], [2,4], [3,1,2], [1,2,4], [3,1,2,4].

Minimums are 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1.
Sum is 17.

My Solution -

```
class Solution {
int MOD = 1000000007;
public int sumSubarrayMins(int[] arr) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        int left = i;
        int right = i;
        while(left > 0 && arr[i] <= arr[left - 1]) {
            left--;
        }
        while(right < arr.length - 1 && arr[i] < arr[right + 1]){
            right++;
        }
        sum = sum + (((i - left + 1) * (right - i + 1)) * (arr[i]));
        sum%=MOD;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

}

My Solution is working for all the test cases but the final one where the input array is quite large and the sum value will exceed the mod value.

My Output:372485114

Expected:667452382

It seems I am making a mistake in my MOD 10^9 + 7 calculation but I can't seem to figure out the issue.

Comment: "return the answer modulo 109 + 7" and "MOD 10^9 + 7 calculation" don't seem to fit. Is the former a typo? If not I'd guess what's meant is `(sum % 109) + 7` (adding the parantheses for clarity).

Comment: @Thomas sorry 109 was a typo, it is (10^9) + 7. I'll fix the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the sum
`sum + (((i - left + 1) * (right - i + 1)) * (arr[i]))`
is overflowing since it is done as `int`.

Change it to `long` (e.g. using `... + 1L...` or casting before multiplying), and do modulo before casting back to `int` (or use `long sum`).

Eventually, depending on range of input numbers, also calculate the module of `(((i - left + 1) * (right - i + 1)) * (arr[i]))` before adding.

Comment: This answer was really helpful. I converted sum to Long and then cast it to int but the problem was still persisting. What fixed it was casting right and left to long in `(((i - (long)left + 1) * ((long)right - i + 1)) * (arr[i]))`.